# Is it possible to downsample an OpenGL ES depth buffer WITHOUT GL_OES_depth_texture?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working on a game for mobile platforms, and I'd like to render my effects to a lower resolution render target than the screen. The issue is, I need to start with the depth buffer from the full screen.

If the hardware supported GL_OES_depth_texture, I imagine it would be relatively straightforward, but unfortunately I don't, so I am wondering if there is any other way to get the depth information from the full screen render and use that for my lower resolution render.

If I can't actually downsample the render buffer, could I bind the higher resolution depth buffer to a render target with a lower resolution color buffer? I can't find any documentation that says that the resolutions of all the different attachments to the frame buffer object have to match in resolution, but I strongly suspect that is a requirement.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In OpenGL ES 2.0 you cannot mix-and-match resolutions between the attachments in a frame buffer object (much like `GL_EXT_framebuffer_obect`). In desktop GL (GL3 / `GL_ARB_framebuffer_object`) it is possible, but in GLES2 it will create a framebuffer incomplete error. It **is** actually documented if you know where to look, see [`glCheckFramebufferStatus (...)`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xml) -- `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DIMENSIONS`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I wouldn't have thought of looking there... Is there any way I can downrez a depth buffer if I don't have the GL_OES_depth_texture extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should render to a texture attached to an FBO.  The texture could have whatever lower resolution you want.  Textures are really the only FBO attachments that are actually useful in OpenGL ES 1.1 and 2.0, on most platforms.

Thanks Andon.

What Andon is suggesting is that you could render into a texture with an ordinary GL_RGBA format that OpenGL ES 2.0 understands, but packing/encoding the color in some more efficient way.  You can do this if you only use that texture to render with a custom fragment shader that unpacks/decodes the custom format you put it in. For example, the values you read from a texture sampler can really be in any format you want.

```
float fR = texture2D(gsuTexture0, gsvTexCoord0).r;
float fG = texture2D(gsuTexture0, gsvTexCoord0).g;
float fB = texture2D(gsuTexture0, gsvTexCoord0).b;
float fA = texture2D(gsuTexture0, gsvTexCoord0).a;

float fDepth = fR;
```

Comment: His problem is that his implementation does not support `GL_OES_depth_texture`. But I think if you amend this answer to point out something like packing the depth value into a color buffer it might solve his problem. It will unfortunately add extra memory bandwidth / storage requirements, which OpenGL ES devices are scarce on to begin with, but it might do the trick. I was going to suggest that myself, but the added memory requirements made me think otherwise.

Comment: Hi Andon, just so I understand what you are proposing, are you saying I render everything again into a color buffer where I record the depth value only? Is there some trick to doing that more efficiently that I am missing? For this effect, I can render the scene again to my lower rez effect buffer, but I am trying to figure out how to avoid that with z buffering.Thanks!

Comment: @ItsLikeYouKnowWhatever: No, there is no trick to do this efficiently, sadly. It is a total hack for algorithms that require the depth buffer to be used like a texture where no hardware / API support exists. But you do not have to do it in a separate pass, you can add an extra MRT target to your shaders that packs the depth into a color buffer; this is how depth textures were often implemented in D3D9.

Comment: I thought MRT were an OpenGL ES 3.0 feature (or Tegra only extension). Is there some way to do it that I am overlooking? Thanks!